# Why adding a custom class to a bootstrap element is not working in chrome but it works in edge?

Tags: html, css, browser, bootstrap-4

I am adding a custom class to some elements which are made using bootstrap 4
here in the navigation  I've added ukzcol which basically changes only background and it is working fine
here is ukzcol class :

```
.ukzcol {
  background-color: rgb(0, 23, 51) !important;
}

 <nav class="nav navbar-nav ukzcol text-white border-bottom sticky-top">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="nav-item navbar-brand ml-3 ">
            <img src="logo.png" alt="logo" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="float-right mr-5 h-100" id="sidebar">
```

but here :

```
            <h6 class="d-inline btn ukzcol ukzcolhv ">
              <i class="fas fa-user "></i> <?php echo $_SESSION['emri']; ?>
            </h6>
            <form action="" method="POST" class="d-inline">
              <button
                type="submit"
                name="logout"
                class="btn  h-100 text-white d-inline ukzcol ukzcolhv"
              >
                Logout <i class="fas fa-power-off"></i>
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

the ukzcolhv which is supposed to change only background color on hover is not working on chrome but in edge yes

here is ukzcolhv class :

```
.ukzcolhv:hover {
  background-color: rgb(3, 35, 75) !important;
}
```

I tried adding -webkit but still not working  , why ? Is there a way to fix it ?

Comment: Works fine: https://www.bootply.com/Z8kHpU60lE  please can you create a [mcve] demonstrating your problem

Comment: @Pete I don't know why it wasn't working and it was fixed on it own, I am trying it with XAMPP and sometimes when I make some changes they are not saved even I save the file  seems that ,that was the problem , again today I had a problem where data was not being pulled from database but I copied the same code created a new file and there was working fine I don't know what is causing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have copied code you have added to jsfiddle, changing colors to be more visible

```
.ukzcolhv:hover {
  background-color: red !important;
}

.ukzcol {
  background-color: green !important;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xf9od1et/8/

and it works fine in chrome. After hovering on h6 element background color is changing.

Comment: it started working now, before I tried even restarting my laptop and the problem wasn't fixed now I didn't do anything and it started working on it's own , maybe because I am making too many changes on the design it is taking sometime until chrome adopts It